# Problem with web scraping - JavaSript on website is disabled

Tags: python, web-scraping

#### Hello,

I've been playing with discord bots (in Python) for a while now and I've come across a problem with scraping information on some websites that protect themselves from data collection by disabling javascript on their side so you can't get to their data.

I have already looked at many websites recommending changing in headers among other things, but it has not helped.

The next step was to use selenium, which returns me this information.

> We're sorry but Hive-Engine Explorer doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.

Code:

```
  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.get("https://he.dtools.dev/richlist/BEE")
  htmlSource = driver.page_source
  print(htmlSource)
```

I also checked how it looks like on the browser side itself and as we can see after entering the page there is no way to see the html file

[Image from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VFKL.png)

My question is, is it possible to bypass such security measures? Unfortunately I wanted to download the information from the API but it is not possible in this case.

Comment: The website is using JavaScript to populate the content, have you tried beautiful soup?

Comment: I'll just put it here as a side advice, but if the data you want is dynamically loaded into the webpage, you can use inspect element and check the Network tab once the page loaded. Find the document you need and if you're lucky, you can just copy the request header as a cURL (bash) command then use postman (import as raw text) to turn it into a python code

Comment: Yes I used beautiful soup also.

Comment: Hm, I have to try this solution, but i think it will not help if I want to put data inside discord bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run Selenium to get this data, the site uses a backend api to deliver the data which you can replicate easily in python:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import json

token = 'BEE'
limit = 100

id_ = int(time.time())

headers =   {
    'accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'content-type':'application/json',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.3'
    }
url = 'https://api.hive-engine.com/rpc/contracts'

payload = {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":id_,"method":"find","params":{"contract":"tokens","table":"balances","query":{"symbol":token},"offset":0,"limit":limit}}
resp = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload)).json()

df= pd.DataFrame(resp['result'])
df.to_csv('HiveData.csv',index=False)

print('Saved to HiveData.csv')
```

Comment: Ohh thank you, you are right I checked it and it works, I used before API but there was problem with Discord it said I make to many requests during taking all data.